# Parsing C/C++ compilation errors printed by GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Given c/cpp/.h files, I want to compile them and find the compilation errors (and warnings).

From the compilation error, I want to produce a structure or table like,

```
{
  level: (ERROR/WARNING)
  fileName: 'hello.cc'
  lineNumber: 24
  char: 5 (if available, or can be skipped)
  message: 'The description of the error'
}
```

1. In Java, there is a Java Compiler API. Is there a similar API for C++?
2. If the only option is to parse the output of gcc or g++, how to parse the error message, so that I can generate an array of the structure as defined above?

I looked at some error messages. For many error messages from gcc, I am looked at, all the error lines start with '`filename: In function main`' or '`filename:lineNumber:column`'
And all the multi line error messages are indented by some whitespace

Is it safe to assume, lines starting with non-whitespace characters are the beginning of error lines?

Note: I had never written c++ programs in the last 10 years, I am building C/C++ support for [Codiva.io online compiler](https://www.codiva.io) (that only supports java at present). I feel, instead of giving a console output, parsing and showing at each line would be a good user experience and saves a ton of time for students.
Will parsing error messages from clang compiler be easier?

Comment: You can use liblang for custom processing of parsed c++ code.

Comment: There is no standard for printing of compiler errors.  They may differ for each compiler vendor.

Comment: The question "how to parse?" is probably too broad for `SO`.

Comment: With templates, the simple structure wouldn't suffice. You typically have an instantiation stack, which has a variable length.

Comment: @MSalters I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @JackDaniels: Just experiment. Create a class `Foo` which cannot be copied, create a `std::vector<Foo> and then call `.resize()`. Now look at that error message. The error is _because_ of `.resize()`  , but it's in detected in another function.

Comment: @MSalters Wouldn't it be possible to concatenate the entire string of error messages as a single string? Again, I haven't done any C++ programs in 10+ years, so I am not able to figure how the error message would look. Would it be possible for you share a link on ideone.com?

Answer (score 4):

With the upcoming gcc 9.0, there is an option to output JSON: `-fdiagnostics-format=json`

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html#index-fdiagnostics-format